# downloaded ruby on rails but it wont run commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, path, rvm

I downloaded ruby on rails on ubuntu 12.10 through this tutorial http://technical-feeds.blogspot.ca/2013/02/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-ruby-on-rails.html.

I did everything and it worked fine.

I checked ruby -v and it came back as ruby 2.0.0p0.  I also checked rails, rubygems and git they came back good.

Then I closed the terminal and opened a new one and tried to check the version but this came back for ruby:

```
 bimbola@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

And this came for rails:

```
bimbola@ubuntu:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

git is still fine though

```
bimbola@ubuntu:~$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.4
```

Comment: Solved. All i had to do was type rvm use 2.0.0. i should probably set it as default....

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, it is customary to write the solution as an Answer and then mark it as accepted. That way, if somebody else has the problem it's clear how to solve it and shows up clearly as "the answer" :)

Comment: ah yea i was going to do that but it said i have to wait 7 hours haha

Comment: Enough time has passed that you can certainly post your answer now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a line to your bashrc to load rvm automatically: (execute in Terminal)

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> .bashrc
```

or load rvm manually:

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to state which version of ruby you want to use. Try this:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

You can also set a particular version of ruby to be used as **default** as shown below

```
rvm --default use 2.0.0
```

RVM (Ruby Version Manager) allows you to install multiple versions of ruby and use any one of them at a time as according to your whim.

To see **all the available ruby versions** on your system try this:

```
rvm list
```